# Update multiple rows in PDO - 1 Column change

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im trying Update multiple rows in PDO. My table **scripts** contains columns **id, style** and **link**, as follows:

```
id  style       link

1   Normalize   http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css
2   Bootstap    http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css
```

I need save two different links for Normalize and Bootstrap, but when I use this construction, interpreter return something wrong. How Can I do this? I want change first link, or second or both together or each separately.

My sql:

```
$connect = new Database();
$connect->query("UPDATE scripts SET link :normalize WHERE style = 'Normalize' AND  SET link :bootstrap WHERE style = 'Bootstrap'");
$connect->bind(':normalize', $_POST['normalize']);
$connect->bind(':bootstrap', $_POST['bootstrap']);
$connect->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE scripts SET link = CASE
WHEN style= 'Normalize' THEN :normalize
WHEN style= 'Bootstrap' THEN :bootstrap
ELSE link
END;
```

Comment: Yes, its very helpful

Comment: Please tell me the good source about PDO database and sql learning?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you try to do is possible. You will need multiple queries if you want to UPDATE rows using multiple conditions.